# The output result of summing an array in c# is always zero

Tags: arrays, sum, output

I am writing a program that calculates the correlation coefficient ,but the output is always 0

I divided the code to know where the problem begins ,and it turns out to be the sum of the array

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace section
        {
            class Program
             {

               static void Main(string[] args)
               {

        Console.WriteLine("please enter the number of values:");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter x values:");
        double[] xVal = new double[n];
        foreach (int val in xVal)
        {
            double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        double sumX = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < xVal.Length; i++)
        {
            sumX += xVal[i];
        }
            // int s = Math.Sqrt(((x[i] - sum / n) * (x[i] - sum / n)) / (n - 1));

        Console.WriteLine(sumX);

        Console.WriteLine("enter y values:");
        double[] yVal = new double[n];

        foreach (int val in yVal)
        {
            double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        double sumY = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < yVal.Length; i++)
        {
            sumY += yVal[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sumY);


      }
   }
}
```

I've tried to use the xVal.Sum() ,but the result is zero
this is the first time it happened with me. I tried to re write the code in many forms ,but  nothing has changed
I don't know what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always get 0 because you are not updating xVal or yVal

`double[] xVal = new double[n];`

This creates an array of empty doubles.

And the following iterates over array of empty doubles resulting in 0:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < xVal.Length; i++)
        {
            sumX += xVal[i];
        }
```

I suggest to replace foreach with:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < xVal.Length; i++)
        {
            double input = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            xVal[i] = input;
        }
```

Assuming you want to modify array values before accessing them, this should work.